# Combine combineLatest is not waiting for the previous operation to fire

Tags: ios, swift, combine, combinelatest

If you try this code in Playgroud:

```
import Combine
import Foundation

struct User {
    let name: String
}

private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
var didAlreadyImportUsers = false
var users = [User]()

func importUsers() -> Future<Bool, Never> {
    Future { promise in
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            sleep(5)
            users = [User(name: "John"), User(name: "Jack")]
            promise(.success(true))
        }
    }
}

func getUsers(age: Int? = nil) ->Future<[User], Error> {
    Future { promise in
        promise(.success(users))
    }
}

var usersPublisher: AnyPublisher<[User], Error> {
    if didAlreadyImportUsers {
        return getUsers().eraseToAnyPublisher()
    } else {
        return importUsers()
            .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
            .combineLatest(getUsers())
            .map { $0.1 }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

usersPublisher
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
    print(completion)
}, receiveValue: { value in
    print(value)
}).store(in: &subscriptions)
```

It will print:

```
[]
finished
```

but I expect:

```
[User(name: "John"), User(name: "Jack")]
finished
```

If I remove the line with `sleep(5)` then it prints the result correctly. It seems like an issue with asynchronicity. It seems like `.combineLatest(getUsers())` is not waiting for `importUsers()` I thought that `combineLatest` is taking care of that ? what I'm missing here ?

(in my real code there is a long running Core Data operations instead of `sleep`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CombineLatest` would have waited, as you correctly expected, but in your case `getUsers` already has a value ready, which was `[]`; i.e what `users` was when `getUsers` ran.

You don't actually need to use `CombineLatest` to "wait" until some async action has happened. You can just chain publishers:

```
return importUsers()
           .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
           .flatMap { _ in
               getUsers()
           }
           .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

In fact, `getUsers` isn't even needed, if you can assume that `users` is populated after `importUsers`:

```
return importUsers()
           .map { _ in
               self.users
           }
           .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Comment: You are right. Interesting that if I create a variable `let users = getUsers()` and use it in both branches of the if this does not work. I guess it's because when I create `let users = getUsers()` it will have a value of `[]` already

Comment: Yes. I think your confusion with this and previous questions stems from the word `Future` - it doesn't actually happen in the "async" future - it could, but it fully depends on when the promise is set. Otherwise, it just copies the value when it runs. So your `getUsers` might as well have been `func getUsers() { Just(users) }` (plus the failure type setting)